# Using GeoLocator for Longitude and Latitude giving the following error in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, geolocation

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Tool
Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added : Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat; GPS.Android
[image]

where GPS is my project name.

[image]

Comment: In your first screenshot, the project name on the far right seems to be "Location_Track".

Comment: are you getting an error when you are installing the nuget packages, or when you build your project?

Answer (score 0):

Just update the  Xamarin.Android.Support packages to the latest version. This should do.